# Can we use or integrate WordPress with ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, content-management-system, peachpie

We want to use WordPress with ASP.NET. Is it possible for ASP.NET and WordPress to work together? If not, what are the alternatives?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/can-i-install-wordpress-on-an-existing-aspnet-site

Comment: What do you mean "work together" - what are you trying to do?  There could be a good solution for whatever problem you're trying to solve that doesn't involve using Wordpress under ASP.NET.

Comment: use Orchard http://www.orchardproject.net/ is the must close System to wordpress at ASP.net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WordPress is written in PHP and runs on Apache, so you can't really run it in ASP.NET. There are methods however that enable you to run it on IIS.

The best way to go with integrating WordPress and ASP.NET is by using one of the supported [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) protocols. You can see more about it here:

*[XML-RPC Support](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support)*

Answer (score 10):

You could [run WordPress using Phalanger](https://github.com/DEVSENSE/Phalanger), which can execute PHP code on the .NET platform (faster that standard PHP!) and allows mixing the PHP and standard .NET languages/frameworks in a single application.

Comment: The link returns 404.

Comment: Phalanger has been updated to .Net Core and renamed into Peachpie.

https://github.com/iolevel/peachpie-wordpress

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it is actually possible.

Check out [WP.NET](http://www.wpdotnet.com):

> WP.NET runs WordPress compiled on the robust, fast and secure .NET
>   Core framework using the cutting edge PeachPie compiler platform.

Comment: This sounds very interesting to me. It is still a beta. Has anybody any experience in using it productive?

Comment: Do you have a demo of how to write a WordPress plugin in C# and deploy it within WordPress using PeachPie?

Answer (score 9):

[PeachPie](https://www.peachpie.io/) is an open source PHP compiler to .NET. This supports ASP.NET  and [ASP.NET Core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_Core), and it is performant.

Comment: Do you have a demo of how to write a WordPress plugin in C# and deploy it within WordPress using PeachPie?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this: https://www.peachpie.io/2017/10/wordpress-plugin-csharp.html

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Visual Studio integrated version:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/gallery/wordpress.aspx

Comment: The link seems to be (effectively) broken (redirects to the generic [https://webgallery.microsoft.com/gallery](https://webgallery.microsoft.com/gallery), *Windows Web App Gallery*).

Answer (score 1):

You can run the PHP file in IIS rather than combine the WordPress file in ASP.NET. Just download the FastCGI and make some configuration.